# s3 is adding random string to uploaded file name

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

im trying to move all my uploads to s3 , i have 2 types of files

1 - files that already exist on my local server

```
 Storage::disk('s3')->put( $file->name , Storage::get($file->path));
```

2 - new files being uploaded

```
    $fileName = $request->file('attachment')->getClientOriginalName();
    $res = Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, $request->attachment);
```

so for the first group there is no problem , files are being uploaded to s3 with the given name

but for the second group , for some reason s3 is adding some random string to the file name like if i upload file and give the name as

`v26-how-to-list-users-in-linux.png`

in response i get

`v26-how-to-list-users-in-linux.png/M53gpy5KvIglCMOBXOnx3KaqghaJ4DQGXzLIkLyA.png`

on the s3  it's adding `/M53gpy5KvIglCMOBXOnx3KaqghaJ4DQGXzLIkLyA.png` to the end of the file name for some reason

here is another example uploaded file with this given name

`v26-testing.txt`

on t he s3 i get

`v26-testing.txt/c36EPgaDMgPb8RKHIyyZCPaxWMJR0g1yV10JVGQF.txt`

it's only happening for the direct uploads ie :

```
$res = Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, $request->attachment);
```

when i move the existing files from local storage to s3 it doesn't add any extra character to the file name

Comment: I recommend that you debug the situation by printing the contents of `$fileName` and see what it contains.

Comment: What's the type of `$request->attachment`? Is it `File`? If so, Laravel then uses different methods for processing the path/file name, it normally expects file contents there. You can try changing it to that if it isn't. Let me know if it works and I'll post as an answer

Comment: It's PHP/Laravel doing this., not S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put` [method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cc3ccc3d68d112ff6e88eb36314fa8c75592311f/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L352) you're using expects file contents as 2nd argument:

```
public function put($path, $contents, $options = [])
```

You pass contents with `Storage::get($file->path)` in the 1st case, but in the 2nd you seem to pass a `File`/`UploadedFile` object which results in `put` [calling](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cc3ccc3d68d112ff6e88eb36314fa8c75592311f/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L363) `putFile` function:

```
return $this->putFile($path, $contents, $options);
```

That then [calls](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cc3ccc3d68d112ff6e88eb36314fa8c75592311f/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L401) `putFileAs` function with your name as 1st `$path` argument and `$file->hashName` as 3rd `$name` argument:

```
return $this->putFileAs($path, $file, $file->hashName(), $options);
```

And finally that function [assigns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cc3ccc3d68d112ff6e88eb36314fa8c75592311f/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L425) the file name that you're seeing:

```
$path = trim($path.'/'.$name, '/'), $stream, $options
```

### Fix

One way to fix it is to change `$request->attachment` to return file contents. Changing it to `$request->attachment->get()` should work if that is standard request `UploadedFile` object (normally you'd use `$request->file('attachment')->get()`).